# Converting MATLAB code to Java code

Tags: java, matlab

I need to call this MATLAB code from Java code. The code clusters an image according to the specified number of clusters and the specified initial cluster centers (i.e. [176;137] in this code).

```
nrows = size(a_image,1);
ncols = size(a_image,2);
double_a_2_image = double(reshape(a_image,nrows*ncols,1));
nColors = 2;

[cluster_idx_2_a cluster_center] =     
kmeans(double_a_2_image,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean','start',repmat([176;137], 
[1,1,3]));

a_pixel_labels_2 = reshape(cluster_idx_2_a,nrows,ncols);
figure('Name','a* image labeled by cluster index: 2 colors'),imshow(a_pixel_labels_2,  
[]);
```

What is the best tool to convert this code into jar file (or maybe .class file)? Another point: I need to run the resulted jar file on a machine that do not have matlab installed. Is that possible or should I install MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) on this machine?

Answer (score 2):

A simple search on google gives you this link : [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.fr/products/javabuilder/), which generate a Java wrapper around your MATLAB code. And for your second question, you won't need it, as the wrapper is taking care of the MATLAB code itself.