# Can I import MATLAB algorithm into Android Studio?

Tags: matlab, android-studio

How can I import a MATLAB algortithm into Android Studio, so I'll be able to run a MATLAB algorithm on photos (captured on Android devices) and show expected results?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know if exists a tool in the Android Studio to translate Matlab code into a Java code, but I found [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html?requestedDomain=true). Pay attention, the Java code generated maybe need be changed to properly work in Android.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864254/converting-matlab-code-to-java-code) can be helpful too.